# How to implement permission check to functions without individual control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, permissions, rbac

Im new to my job and bigger scaled react projects. I've been tasked to produce scenarios about how to implement RBAC to a web platform. In the project there is a navbar on the left which lists the routes (this is done by fuse-config). I implemented the RBAC to project by assigning routes to roles. So the left navbar generates itself based on the user's role and routes its assigned to. I created the database shown below in mongodb.

```
[
    {
        firstname: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        username: 'jane.doe',
        email: 'jane.doe@example.com',
        password: '123456',
        role: 'staff',
        menu_items: [
            {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                type: 'item',
                icon: 'layers',
                url: '/dashboard'
            },
            { title: 'Alarm', type: 'item', icon: 'layers', url: '/alarm' },
            {
                title: 'Devices',
                type: 'item',
                icon: 'layers',
                url: '/devices'
            }
        ],
        permissions: ['read','edit']
    },
```

This db consists of 4 collections, user which user info comes from including role, menu which the routes listed in left navbar, roles which roles and the routes every role can navigate to defined, and permissions to define what permissions assigned to roles. The example above gets the user info with her role, her routes she can go to and her permissions which she can do in her components.

e.g Jane can see the alarm and devices page and can do read or edit operations in there. In devices component there 3 operations one can perform which are adding a new device, editing one or deleting. In this case Jane can only edit. These permissions given randomly by me.

I tried to put id's on the buttons that perform operations to define which one is add or edit. Then added useEffect hook to get all the buttons in the component and check their id. If it exists and user has the permission then she can use it. If its not then she cant use. Code shown below is self-explanatory I think. The problem with this approach is that the buttons are MUI Button components and when they are disabled, only their border is disabled, I can still use the button when I click in the middle section or on the text which is again in the middle section.

```
    useEffect(() => {
 
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        buttons.forEach((button) => {
            console.log(button.id);

            if (button.id && !permissions.includes(button.id)) {
                button.disabled = true;
                // button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                //     event.preventDefault();
                //     alert("You don't have permission for this action...");
                // });
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

**My problem ** is how can I implement these permissions to check if user can perform addData, editData or deleteData without individually controlling these functions? My team lead doesnt want to control the every function with if's. I need some ideas.

Comment: How you're currently approaching this (using native DOM methods within React to update the DOM) is the wrong approach. You should go back a revisit how React works before you get any further into this.

Comment: You can use an authorization library like CASL to handle client-side RBAC. This will help you display components and features based on CRUD definitions https://casl.js.org/v6/en/package/casl-react

Comment: @Andy I did that later and crossed that idea.

Comment: @KyleLambert This looks like individiual handling of components which my team lead doesnt want. Anyway we decided on constructing a middleware to check the permission before sending the request. Thanks for the replies.